# Logical Deduction an example

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to prove the Negation introduction (a natural deduction rule)
$$
\{(\alpha\to\beta),(\alpha\to(\neg\beta))\}\vdash(\neg\alpha)
$$

The axioms of the chosen logical system are:

- $(\alpha\to(\beta\to\alpha))$,
- $((\alpha\to(\beta \to\gamma))\to ((\alpha\to\beta)\to(\alpha\to\gamma)))$,
- $(((\lnot\beta)\to(\lnot\alpha))\to(((\lnot\beta)\to\alpha)\to\beta))$.

The only inference rule is Modus Ponens (MP).

For this purpose I've written a Java program that iteratively generate new axioms and check for MP. Even if I let the program generates 20'000 steps (a part of which are MPs), I do not get $(\neg\alpha)$.

I assume that I have a program error, but I formulate my question as follows:

- Do I have a conceptional error?
- Do someone has the mathematical solution? (This would help me to debug the program)

**EDIT** after the problem has been solved.

The program seems to work correctly and is able to solve:

1. $\{\alpha\to\beta,\beta\to\gamma\}\vdash\alpha\to\gamma$ is solved in 12 iterantions
2. $\{\alpha,\alpha\to\beta\}\vdash\beta$ is solved in 1 iterantion
3. $\vdash\alpha\to\alpha$ is solved in 3 iterantions
4. $\{\alpha\to(\beta\to\gamma),\beta\}\vdash\alpha\to\gamma$ is solved in 3 iterantions
5. $\vdash(\neg\neg\alpha)\to\alpha$ is solved in 130 iterantions!

For the 5th solution I give the last part of the log (+2M steps and +6M subformulas):

```
DEGUG end step 130 [Steps 2254228, formulas 6642034, results 0/1]
DEGUG Step, 131
DEGUG Next formula I(I(N(1),N(N(1))),1)
DEGUG MP, 1
DEGUG MP, 2
DEGUG MP, 3
DEGUG Found result I(N(N(1)),1)
DEGUG MP, 4
DEGUG MP, 5
DEGUG MP, 6
DEGUG MP, 7
DEGUG MP, 8
DEGUG MP, 9
DEGUG end step 131 [Steps 2306683, formulas 6796093, results 1/1]
DEGUG successfull = true
DEGUG END successfull = true [Steps 2306683, formulas 6796093, results 1/1]


Deduction:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  9 : A3                   (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → (((¬1) → (¬1)) → 1))
156 : A1                   ((¬1) → ((¬(¬1)) → (¬1)))
162 : A1                   ((¬(¬1)) → ((¬1) → (¬(¬1))))
185 : A2                   (((¬1) → ((¬(¬1)) → (¬1))) → (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → ((¬1) → (¬1))))
226 : 156 185 MP           (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → ((¬1) → (¬1)))
53102 : A2                   ((((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → (((¬1) → (¬1)) → 1)) → ((((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → ((¬1) → (¬1))) → (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → 1)))
53659 : A2                   (((¬(¬1)) → (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → 1)) → (((¬(¬1)) → ((¬1) → (¬(¬1)))) → ((¬(¬1)) → 1)))
55067 : 9 53102 MP           ((((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → ((¬1) → (¬1))) → (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → 1))
56341 : 226 55067 MP         (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → 1)
7079229 : A1                   ((((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → 1) → ((¬(¬1)) → (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → 1)))
7158204 : 56341 7079229 MP     ((¬(¬1)) → (((¬1) → (¬(¬1))) → 1))
7160210 : 7158204 53659 MP     (((¬(¬1)) → ((¬1) → (¬(¬1)))) → ((¬(¬1)) → 1))
7215262 : 162 7160210 MP       ((¬(¬1)) → 1)
```

This explains why I'm not able to solve the problem of the question. For a *brute force* method it is too complex.

Comment: Oh man, huge undertaking.  Why Java? Worst language ever.  Im sure there are plenty better.  I have never studied this level of logic so I cannot contribute much.  But I do notice that the assertion youre trying to show is that "proof by contradiction" works. Am I mistaken? Isnt that what it boils down to?  If it doesnt work, does that not imply that contradictions are not prohibited in your system?

Comment: Therre is huge literature on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving. Sophisticated systems like Prover9 or Vampire will have no difficulty finding this kind of proof. Unless you use powerful algorithms like resolution and an efficient implementation, you will be unlikely to get good results.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum : I'm looking for a deduction. Possible steps: 1) premisses 2) axioms 3) MPs. Programming language: with C I would need 10 times more time...

Comment: @RobArthan: thank you very much for the link and product names. I assumed that there were such libraries, but I needed less than two days to write the program and I learned a lot.

Comment: The difference between Java and C is unlikely to make much difference. Unless you use a sophisticated algorithm to guide the proof search, the search space will grow far too fast.

Comment: I think my point is that if $\alpha\land\neg\alpha$ is permissible in your logic then proof by contradiction tells you nothing.  You could not conclude $\neg\alpha$ from $\alpha\to\beta$ and $\alpha\to\neg\beta$.  Im asking you if contradictions are allowed in your logic or not. Or is that something you dont yet know? I had presumed that contradiction wasnt allowed in any logic.

Comment: I suspect that what you are trying to prove is provable. The key intermediate result you are likely to need is $\lnot\lnot \alpha \to \alpha$. Unfortunately, I don't have a reference to hand just now.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: I do not understand enough to answer your question. I'm at the and of chapter 1 of Bilaniuk. A Problem Course in Mathematical Logic. I'm looking for a deduction (a list of steps as before that go from the two premisses to the result).

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: the OP's language doesn't include conjunction. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus for a similar axiomatization of the $\to$, $\lnot$ fragment of propositional logic due to Lukasiewicz.

Comment: @RobArthan As I previously stated, I dont know enough about this higher level logic to contribute much.  It surprises me though that $\alpha$ and $\neg\alpha$ could both be true simultaneously, and this not be considered contradictory, simply and solely because conjunction to $\alpha\land\neg\alpha$ isnt allowed.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum In the system that I'm using $(\alpha\land\beta)$ is written as $(\lnot(\alpha\to(\lnot\beta)))$. But it has not the meaning of conjuction per se; it is just a shortcut.

Comment: See Mendelson, [ML](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/mendelson.pdf) page 38 for the derivation of the two versions of Double Negation. With them and Syllogism and Deduction Th, you can use Ax.3 with $\lnot \beta$ in palce of $\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hypothetical Syllogism* : $\alpha \to \beta, \beta \to \gamma \vdash \alpha \to \gamma$

*Double Negation 1* : $\vdash \lnot \lnot \alpha \to \alpha$

*Double Negation 2* : $\vdash  \alpha \to \lnot \lnot \alpha$

---

1) $(α→β)$ --- premise

2) $(α→ ¬β)$ --- premise

3) $\vdash (¬¬α → ¬β ) → ((¬¬α → β) → ¬α)$ --- Ax.3

4) $(¬¬α → ¬β )$ --- from 2) and DN-1 by HS

5) $(¬¬α → β )$ --- from 1) and DN-1 by HS

> 6) $¬α$ --- from 3), 4) and 5) by *modus ponens* twice.

Comment: thank you! the proofs of HS and DN-1 are also in [A Problem Course in Mathematical Logic, Stefan Bilaniuk](http://euclid.trentu.ca/math/sb/pcml/pcml-16.pdf) pg 12 and 13